# Using LinkedList in FreeRTOS fails to save values

Tags: c++, memory, linked-list, arduino, freertos

I'm running FreeRTOS 10.0 on Arduino with Atmel 328P and 2560

I need to utilize a LinkedList, and rather re-invent the wheel, am using the [LinkedList Arduino library here.](https://github.com/ivanseidel/LinkedList).

The library works in a standard Arduino (loop) configuration, but when I put it into the RTOS, it fails to save values.  The size() counter increments as if it is saving, but all values returned are '0'.

I initially expected this was an implementation issue with the library, but trying out [Qlist](https://github.com/SloCompTech/QList) yields the same results.

Is there something special I need to do for a LInkedList to properly handle saving values in FreeRTOS?

FreeRTOS Code:

```
#include <Arduino_FreeRTOS.h>
#include <LinkedList.h>

void TaskTest( void *pvParameters );

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);

  while (!Serial) {
    ;
  }

  xTaskCreate(
    TaskTest
    ,  (const portCHAR *)"Test"
    ,  128
    ,  NULL
    ,  2
    ,  NULL );
}

void loop()
{

}

void TaskTest( void *pvParameters __attribute__((unused)) )
{
  LinkedList<byte> list;

  for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    list.add(i);
    Serial.print(i);
    Serial.print(',');
    Serial.print(list.get(list.size() - 1));
    Serial.print(',');
    Serial.println(list.size());
  }

  for (;;)
  {
    vTaskDelay(1);
  }
}
```

FreeRTOS Code Output (truncated):

```
248,0,249
249,0,250
250,0,251
251,0,252
252,0,253
253,0,254
254,0,255
255,0,256
```

Standard Arduino Code:

```
#include <LinkedList.h>

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  while (!Serial) {
    ;
  }

}

void loop() {
  LinkedList<byte> list;

  for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    list.add(i);
    Serial.print(i);
    Serial.print(',');
    Serial.print(list.get(list.size() - 1));
    Serial.print(',');
    Serial.println(list.size());
  }

  for (;;)
  {
  }

}
```

Standard Arduino Code Output (truncated):

```
249,249,250
250,250,251
251,251,252
252,252,253
253,253,254
254,254,255
255,255,256
```

Answer (score 1):

The LinkedList class allocates new nodes dynamically on the heap using the 'new' operator. Does your FreeRTOS build have enough heap allocated, like your non-FreeRTOS loop code? If you are using the heap_3 allocator with FreeRTOS itself then all FreeRTOS objects and task stacks will take up space from the system heap too.

Comment: That may entirely be possible.  I had experienced stack overflows, which would freeze the processor, but had forgotten that dynamically allocated data would go to the heap.  

I would find it weird that it doesn't even save a single value though, wouldn't you?  Though would mean that I had 0 heap (or near-0) available to begin with.  

I'll force the RTOS to print the heap once I get to the device again and report back.